# How to get all order items using sales_order_grid_collection_load_before in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sales-order, items

Below is my code but I can't fetch order items details,just I need order items from sales_order_grid_collection object,I also try `getAllItems()` but it does not work

This is my config.xml file

```
<sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <package_module_sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
                        <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>customOrderGridCollection</method>
                    </package_module_sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
```

this is observer.php

```
public function customOrderGridCollection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
 {  
            $orderGridCollection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
            // $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();
   foreach ($orderGridCollection as $order) 
   {
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) //$order->getAllItems() not work 
    {
        // $item->getData('product_id') not work 

    }
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have using Collection `load_before` event and using ***nested foreach loop*** that it have creating lot of time  taken for  execute the observer code.That make huge issue

My suggestion to ***avoid to multiple times order and  order item load***.
Use this process getting the item data.

- First get all  order ids using `->getAllIds()`

> `$orderGridCollection->getAllIds();`

- Then filter ***order item collection***
  `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')`  by ***order ids***

> `$itemCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('in'=>$orderGridCollection->getAllIds()));`

If you want ***all  records of specific one column*** value then add `getColumnValues($colName)`. Just like

> `$itemCollection->getColumnValues('product_id')`

Comment: Amit, I have one doubt. Collection would be available in `load_before` event ?

Comment: rajeev.. i will get back to you shortly..

Answer (score 1):

May be the event that you are listening is wrong. I think you should use `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after` in this case. Because `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` is an event is dispatched just before the collection get loaded. That means the real collection is not available in that event.

If you can't find the order items in `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after`, then another solution that comes to my mind is use the event `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` and then join the table `sales_flat_order` or `sales_flat_order_item` into the collection. You can do join somewhat like this.

```
$collection->join(
    'sales/order_item', 'order_id=entity_id',
    array('name'=>'name', 'sku' =>'sku', 'qty_ordered'=>'qty_ordered' ),
    null, 'left'
 );
```

Then use `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after` to grab the collection again.